# Actualizar Java 1.5 a 1.8 en Aplicación

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, ivy

Os cuento, tengo una aplicación que está en Java 1.5, nos han mandado pasarla a Java 1.8 pero sin rehacerla, simplemente modificando los archivos de configuración para que esté preparada en java 1.8.

Bien, he estado leyendo y casi en todos los sitios ponia de actualizar el pom para que en vez de que la version de java fuera la 5, sea la 8.. el problema es que en esta aplicación en concreto no hay pom.xml, ya que no está en spring.

La aplicación ahora mismo se desplega en un jboss y la idea es que con el java 8 se desplegara en un tomcat...

Para dar mas información, tambien se usa el ivy.xml..

Pero ahora mismo no veo muy bien que ficheros se deberían de tocar para actualizar la versión..

¿Me podrías dar un poco de luz sobre este tema?

Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Solo por aclarar, `pom.xml` no es un fichero que tenga que ver con spring, es un fichero de configuración de maven. Parece que las dependencias de tu proyecto están gestionadas con Apache Ivy.

Comment: Hola Ordago, sí perdona me expliqué mal! está con Apache Ivy las dependencias :)

Comment: ¿Tienes un fichero `build.xml`? Puede que tenga una propiedad target donde puedes especificar la version de java en la que quieras compilar el código. Ejemplo: <property name="target" value="1.8" />

Comment: Hola Ordago, sí en el build.xml veo que está configurado así:

    <target name="compile" depends="import" description="Compila el codigo fuente">
        <javac
       encoding="windows-1252"
            destdir="${classes}"
            debug="${debug}"
            debuglevel="${debuglevel}"
      target="1.5"
        >

Nose si cambiando el target a 1.8 ya tendriamos nuestro proyecto en java 1.8..

luego otro tema sería que quizas haya funciones que se usan ahora en 1.5 que estén deprecadas en 1.8..

Comment: Eso es lo que tienes que cambiar, el target y ya lo tendrías en java 1.8 si lo generas usando ese build.xml. Respecto a los métodos `@Deprecated`, no puedo saber si te va a dar muchos problemas porque dependerá de lo grande que sea tu proyecto, pero cuando me ha tocado a mí avanzar de versión no ha sido tan problemático como nos esperabamos. Lo malo hubiera sido si tuvieras que haber retrocedido de versión.

Answer (score -1):

Si estás usando Eclipse, bastaría con cambiar los Projects Facets.

En **project explorer**, haz *click derecho* sobre:

> Proyecto->Properties-> Project Facets.

También puedes hacerlo así

> Ctrl + 3. Escribe Project Facets

Una vez dentro, busca Java, y cambia la **versión 1.5 a 1.8**.

Haz click en **Apply and Close.**, y recompilar el proyecto:

> Project -> Clean

También puedes cambiar la configuración en:

> Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler

Desde aquí seleccionar la versión Java.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Pero esto no está cambiando ningun archivo de configuracion, no? es decir, entiendo que en el proyecto habrá archivos de configuración donde le digas que es java 1.5 y haciendolo de esta forma no se modifica nada.

Comment: En eclipse, la configuración del proyecto se encuentra dentro de la carpeta .settings, en el fichero org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs. Ahí es donde se cambia cuando tocas los facets.

Comment: Imagino que te preguntarás, ¿Cómo sabe el entorno de ejecución (JRE) que tiene que tratar la aplicación como Java 8? Porque al compilar el proyecto con el JDK 8, tus  .class resultantes tienen un atributo, major, que indica qué versión del JDK lo ha compilado. Por eso, el JRE no necesita un fichero de configuración para saber la versión de Java de tu aplicación.